# How to get IIS site name in NLog

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, nlog

I'm trying to log the site name of multiple IIS sites, dynamically, without providing the name as a variable for each site individually. My NLog configuration is centralized, meaning that every site refers to the same NLog configuration file. Also, I can't make changes to the sites themselves, I can only modify the configuration file.

When dealing with, for example, a WinForms application, I can use the ${processname} layout renderer. For an IIS site, however, this will return the ISS application pool process name, like w3wp. But this doesn't allow me to differentiate between multiple IIS sites.

My current solution is checking whether the process name is w3wp, and then using the ${windows-identity} layout renderer, as this will return the name of the application pool when the Identity is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity. But this is not always possible/wanted.

I've also been looking at using ${basedir}, but I can't find a way to strip any unnecessary parts, as I would only need the last folder of the path.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a built-in feature to know this kind of information, but you could create your own LayoutRenderer, the code to create it is as follows:

```
namespace NLog.Extensions.LayoutRenderers
{
    using System.Text;
    using NLog.LayoutRenderers;

    [LayoutRenderer("IISSiteName")]
    public class IISSiteName : LayoutRenderer
    {
        protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            if (System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost != null)
                builder.Append(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName());
        }
    }
}
```

You must compile this code and add the DLL using the  tag in your NLog.config file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true" >

  <extensions>
    <add assemblyFile="c:\\your-path-to-dll" />
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="file" fileName="${basedir}\file.txt" layout="${date} ${level} ${IISSiteName} "/>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>

</nlog>
```

if you add the compiled DLL as reference to your project you must change the assemblyPath for assembly and add it as a Namespace.Class format.

I made it work on my PC, so it should work correctly. Tell me if not.

Greetings

Comment: Did the job for every site I tested so far. Accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your NLog.config file, add something like this:

```
<parameter name="@WebsiteName" layout="${gdc:WebsiteName}"/> <!-- custom field! -->
```

Then, when you initialize your logger, do something like this:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("WebsiteName",System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName());
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** I now realize you can't update the actual web source. Sorry. Would this work better (you'd have to add NLog.Exended.dll and extension nodes to the config file):

```
<parameter name="@WebsiteName" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME}"/> <!-- IIS Server Variable -->
```

Maybe it's HTTP_HOST or SERVER_NAME. I always get those switched.

You'd have to add Extensions nodes the NLog.config file, as well as the NLog.Extended.dll:

```
<extensions><add assembly="NLog.Extended" assemblyFile="NLog.Extended.dll"/></extensions>
```

Comment: Tino can't modify the code of the running apps, it's a good idea though.

Comment: this does not work. I added two serverVariables to my working example: SERVER_NAME wrote "localhost" while HTTP_HOST wrote "localhost:55021", the customRenderer in my answer writes "Pricing.Estandar.Ejemplos.Logs.Web(1)" which corresponds to the Site Name. The SiteName is something you get from IIS, not from the HTTP_CONTEXT, so I think you can't get it through the request, not sure though

Comment: This should work when using the APP_POOL_ID, but some of the sites are WCF REST services (apparently) and the server variables wind up empty. I would have preferred to use this solution (after the edit), as it seems to be the most straightforward.

Comment: (Would have wanted to upvote your answer (and the accepted one as well) but I can't yet...)

Answer (score 2):

There is now a [**NLog.Web package**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web) that has a layout renderer [**${iis-site-name}**](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/IIS-site-name-Layout-Renderer) that should do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've not understood your limitations but is there anything stopping you using the asp net application layout renderer:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetApplication-layout-renderer

```
${aspnet-application:variable=String}
```

??

Comment: This requires me to define the site name as variable for each site individually. Which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Can you use different app pools?  I take you cannot change any code so writing a custom renderer is not an option?

Comment: Each site has it's own application pool. Writing a custom renderer is indeed not an option.

Comment: With distinct app pools you could get Server Variables that identifies the App Pool by name and pass that to the aspnet-application renderer.

Comment: @Tino, as I posted in my answer, writing a CustomRenderer should be an option, you can load DLL extending your NLog dinamically by using the '<extension>' tag. So you do not need to modify any code inside the application.

Answer (score 0):

A nlog.config like the following works for my dotnet core projects. Just set the fileName as `fileName="C:\[yourPath]\Log\${iis-site-name}${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.txt"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    autoReload="true"
    internalLogLevel="info"
    internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

    <!-- the targets to write to -->
    <targets>
        <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
        <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="C:\inetpub\archive\Log\${iis-site-name}${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.txt"
                layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
    </targets>

    <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
    <rules>
        <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
        <!--<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="allfile" />-->

        <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" />
        <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```